# how to Retrieve the parameters of document.write using userscript

Tags: javascript, dom, userscripts

In my Project i am supposed to identify the dynamically created tags which can be done in scripts through document.write. i created a hook for document.write but it is not retrieving all the document.write functions.My code is as follows

**UPDATE:**

```
var oldDocumentWrite = document.write; 
document.write      = function (text) 
{        
  console.log(text);
}
```

where text is the parameters of document.write.

I included this in my userscript. How can i get the parameters of document.write.Is there any mistake in my code.

Comment: Solution: Do not parse HTML with a RegEx, but use DOM methods, eg `document.getElementsByTagName('script');`, or DOM mutation events: `DOMNodeInserted`.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('script');` does not retrieve dynamically created tags.

Comment: Obviously in conjunction with your element insertion detection method.

Comment: This works when the Node is Inserted i.e, sometimes sometimes this happens when we perform some action on the page but i want to track all the dynamically created tags even before they are created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this again by using the below code now i am getting all the document.write methods.

```
 var oldDocumentWrite = document.write; 
 document.write      = function (str) 
 {        
    var elem = oldDocumentWrite.apply (document,arguments); 
    console.log("Document.write Parameters:",str);
    return elem;
 }
```